# return soap message with error on faults

Tags: java, web-services, spring-integration

Client doesn't want to get fault soap message anf prefer smth like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:TestResponse xmlns:ns2="http://teclot.com/exchange">
         <ns2:return>ERROR</ns2:return>
      </ns2:TestResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

We use Spring Integration in project. I thought that it should look like

```
    <int-ws:inbound-gateway id="wsInboundGateway"
                            request-channel="inboundChannel"
                            marshaller="serverSchemaMarshaller"
                            unmarshaller="serverSchemaMarshaller"
                            error-channel="errorChannel" />

     <bean id="errorWrapper" class="pro.tender.customer.ws2apmq.ErrorWrapper"/>

    <int:transformer id="errorWrap" input-channel="errorChannel" ref="errorWrapper" output-channel="inboundChannel" />
```

where is my mistake?

```
`
```

Comment: Give some more background info on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sounds like your client needs to understand that they must handle soap faults that occur outside of your managed code anyway(server errors, client errors), so it shouldn't be a big deal to handle logically thrown soap faults from within your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: what does your `ErrorWrapper`? Show its code, please. At least what does he do with `ErrorMessage` and what he retunrs ?
But your issue is here `output-channel="inboundChannel"`.
Remove this attribute and if your `ErrorWrapper` doesn't return `Message<?>` you'll get expected result.